# Disabling / Enabling POE on a port by port basis on a netgear smart switch

Tags: networking, switch, power-over-ethernet

Ive got a Netgear GS108PEv3 switch.

How can i enable / disable the POE function on a port by port basis on this switch, i couldnt find anything in the manual or by hunting around the web GUI.

[image: screenshot of web gui on GS108PEv3 switch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable the POE ports in this switch.

The ports are auto-sensing,

(802.1af)
they will enable PoE once the switch has discovered a signature resistance on the designated pair.

POE+ or 802.1at devices which, your switch uses. These leverage a.c impedance using a capacitor on the phantom transformer circuit to detect a POE compliant device. It then uses LLDP-MED to negotiate power levels of the device.

None of the POE versions will supply a legacy device (non POE compliant) power if it doesn't detect the signature circuitry signal of a POE standard.

If your model supports the console, you could try there. But it looks like it was left out by design.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, as long as its auto-sensing thats fine, i just wanted to make sure non POE devices plugged into POE ports (due to lack of port space) would be ok.

Comment: "once a PoE packet request has been sent by the device connecting to it" is pretty much nonsense as a device can't send any packets before it's powered up. PoE uses MDI sensing to detect powered devices (using signature resistors).

Comment: Lol, that was taken from netgears answer at their support site. I didn't even notice the mix of 802.1at/lldp-med and 802.1af. thanks for the comment. I updated it